# drop down list in django shows object for foreign key field

Tags: python, django

I am using models to auto generate a form in Django. Here is my code

```
class Dependent(models.Model):
    primarystudentid = models.ForeignKey('Students', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='PrimaryStudentID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    dependentname = models.CharField(db_column='DependentName', max_length=100)  # Field name made lowercase.
    relation = models.CharField(db_column='Relation', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.primarystudentid)
```

primarystudentid is an auto generated field in Students table. I have tried unicode and str. But i am still getting the value of primarystudentid in dropdown as Students object. I tried a lot of things from stack overflow and other sites but it doesn't seem to be working. 
Python version Python 2.7.13
Django version 1.9.13
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: define __str__ (self): method in the student table also, and return the column value using self.column_name in the student table , then it will show the value in the drop down list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the **str** or **unicode** method of your **Student** table (not the Dependent table), and return name or whatever field you want to show in the dropdown.

Example:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __str__(self):
    return u'{0}'.format(self.name)
```

P.S: Please update the name of field **dependentname** to just **name**, because it is quite obvious that if this is in the Dependent model then it's the name of dependent.

Answer (score 1):

you need to reference the field in the other table.

```
dep = Dependent.objects.first()
dep.primarystudentid.name # This would be the name
```

in your str example

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{0}".format(self.primarystudentid.name)
```

just worth noting that this can easily cause a lot of extra queries to be generated.